# How to serialize fields?

Tags: c#, serialization

I try to write my own serializer. But this serializer serializes only properties. How to serialize fields ? Classes which I have are shown below:

```
namespace MySerializer
{
class MySerializer
{
    private Type targetType;
    public MySerializer(Type targetType)
    {
        this.targetType = targetType;
        if (!targetType.IsDefined(typeof(DataContractAttribute), false))
            throw new Exception("No soup for you");
    }

    public void WriteObject(Stream stream, Object graph)
    {
        IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> serializbleProperties =
            targetType.GetProperties().Where(p => p.IsDefined(typeof (DataMemberAttribute), false));
        var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        writer.WriteLine("<" + targetType.Name + ">");
        foreach (PropertyInfo propInfo in serializbleProperties)
            writer.Write("\t<" + propInfo.Name + ">" + propInfo.GetValue(graph, null) +
                         "</" + propInfo.Name + ">"); 
        writer.WriteLine("</" + targetType.Name + ">");
        writer.Flush();


    }

    }
}

[DataContract]
class Person
{ 
    [DataMember]
  public  string _family;
    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person name = new Person
        {
            _family = "big",
            FirstName = "Vasy",
            LastName = "Bobrow",
            Age = 20
        };
        MySerializer serializer = new MySerializer(name.GetType());
        MemoryStream someRam = new MemoryStream();
        serializer.WriteObject(someRam, name);
        someRam.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        Console.WriteLine(XElement.Parse(
            Encoding.ASCII.GetString(someRam.GetBuffer()).Replace("\0", "")));
    }
}
```

To serialize fields   I can use FieldsInfo  instead of PropetryInfo  or  there is another way?

Comment: First of all, why are you writing your own serializer? Is it just out of curiosity or do you have another purpose?

Comment: Check MSDN for something about Type.GetFields

Comment: I'm writing my own serializer because I'm curious. I don't have another purpose. I would like to know  how to add to my project serialization of fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question really isn't about serialization, it is more about how to do reflection. If you want to return both Fields and Properties you need to use the method [`GetMembers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dk6tw7k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and specify that you are looking for properties and fields.

```
public void WriteObject(Stream stream, Object graph)
{
    IEnumerable<MemberInfo> serializbleMembers =
        targetType.GetMembers(BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic )
                  .Where(p => p.IsDefined(typeof (DataMemberAttribute), false));
    var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    writer.WriteLine("<" + targetType.Name + ">");
    foreach (MemberInfo memberInfo in serializbleMembers)
    {
        writer.Write("\t<" + memberInfo.Name + ">");
        var fieldInfo = memberInfo as FieldInfo;
        if(fieldInfo != null)
        {
            writer.Write(fieldInfo .GetValue(graph, null).ToString());
        }

        var propInfo= memberInfo as PropertyInfo;
        if(propInfo != null)
        {
            writer.Write(propInfo.GetValue(graph, null).ToString());
        }

        writer.Write("</" + memberInfo.Name + ">"); 
    }
    writer.WriteLine("</" + targetType.Name + ">");
    writer.Flush();


}
```

However I doubt this your WriteObject method will be very useful, both your and my `WriteObject` method relies on the `.ToString()` value to be overridden (yours has a implicit `.ToString()` when you do `">" +` whatever is on the right hand side of the `+` has `.ToString()` called on it for you). For example you tried to use your class on something like

```
[DataContract]
class Example
{
    public Example()
    {
        ExampleArray = new int[] {1, 2};
    }

    [DataMember]
    int[] ExampleArray {get; set;}
}
```

you would get

```
<Example>
    <ExampleArray>System.Int32[]</ExampleArray >
</Example>
```

as your output because any class that has not had `.ToString()` overridden just outputs `.GetType().Name`.